# Excel VBA - select to end of column minus two rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in a situation where I want to start from a cell, E9 say, and I want to select down to the end of the column EXCEPT I don't want to include the last 2 cells in the column.

So for example

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

I want to select the range A:C in the column but NOT D and E.

Have tried

```
ActiveSheet.Range("E9", ActiveSheet.Range("E9").End(xlUp)).Select
```

but don't know how to lop off the last two cells...

Comment: select(range(A1).end(xldown).offset(-2,0))

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - sorry, you're right. Here is the correct syntax I had intended: `Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(-2, 0)).Select`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Range("E9", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(-2)).Select
```

Though as a rule of thumb, you should avoid Select statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim r as range

set r = activesheet.range(activesheet.range("A1"), _
                        activesheet.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup))

if r.rows.count>2 then set r=r.resize(r.rows.count-2,1)
```